# Spring MVC controller throwing 415 error media unsupported for JSON request

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc, dojo

I have looked at all the other answers for this problem and tried most of the solutions but nothing seems to work.  I am using Dojo.xhrPOST(xhrArgs) which obviously comes after the xhrArgs definition.

my xhrArgs:

```
 xhrArgs = 
 {
     headers: 
     { 
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
     },
  'url': thisUrl,
  'postData':requestString,
  'dataType' : 'json',
  'userId': userId,
  'measurementSystem': measurementSystem,
  'systemId': openedSystemId,
  'handleAs': 'text',
  'load': function(data)
     {
         // Replace newlines with nice HTML tags.
         data = data.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
         dojo.byId(target).innerHTML = data;
     },
    'error': function(error)
    {
       dojo.byId(target).innerHTML = error;
    }
};
```

and my controller method signature and annotations are as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveSystemConditions", method= RequestMethod.POST,  headers =                                                                               {"content-type=application/json"})
 public String saveSystemConditions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @Valid @RequestBody Load load, BindingResult result)
```

and my requestString as shown in the xhrArgs is

```
"{'systemID':'76', 'system.systemType':'1', 'unitsOfMeasure':'english', 'loadID':'63', 'dispersionInstallationLocation':'Duct+or+AHU', 'humidificationSystemType':'1', 'totalAirVolume':'1200.0', 'desiredDryBulb':'70.0', 'desiredAirMoistureType':'2', 'desiredAirMoisture':'55.0', 'outsideAirConditionsType':'1', 'outsideAirIntakeRateMeasuredAs':'0', 'loadCountry':'United+States', 'outsideAirVolumeMeasuredIn':'0', 'loadState':'Minnesota', 'outsideAirIntakeRate':'25.0', 'loadCity':'Minneapolis', 'elevationFeet':'837.0', 'outsideDryBulb':'-6.8', 'outsideAirMoisture':'57.3', 'userEnteredLoad':'7.43'}"
```

I get 
   415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
David

Comment: Can you share your MVC configuration? Do you have jackson library in your classpath? If you are returning a string value you can remove the `'Accept': 'application/json'` header and try. Here the problem looks like the application does not know how to convert the returned value `String` to a `json` object. If you have jackson library in your classpath it will take care of this

Comment: I have this in my pom.xml 
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
 <version>1.7.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency><groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.5</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>

Comment: I updated to 1.9.11 and update my pom to reflect that version.  Still get 415 unsupported media type.

Comment: what specific jackson libraries do I need in my classpath.  I have asl-core and asl-mapping.  Do I need annotations too?  or what specifically do I need?

Comment: here is the section of pom.xml 
`<dependency>`
`  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>`
`  <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>`
`  <version>1.9.11</version>`
`  <scope>compile</scope>`
` </dependency>`
` <dependency>`
`    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>`
`  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>`
`    <version>1.9.11</version>`
`  <scope>compile</scope>`
` </dependency>`

Comment: sorry can't seem to format the pom text

Comment: @ArunPJohny  sorry didn't know I was supposed to include your name to let you know I replied.

Comment: I do not have anything much to add now, but if you are ready debug the problem by going throw the spring code I can help you. first you need to get the source code of spring, if you are using eclise rt click on the project > select maven > select download source

Comment: @ArunPJohny  I have downloaded source.  I put a break point right at my save function definition but it never hits it.  How do I intercept and step through the code before that point.

Comment: There is a class called `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`, put a break point in the `resolveArgument()` method, also check the value of `messageConverters` property. It should have a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`

Comment: You may also have to check `WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getDefaultMediaTypes()` to see whether jackson support is getting added. One more thing what is the spring version used and `<mvc:annotation-config />` is present your context?

Comment: @ArunPJohny  I am running Spring 3.1.0  I would past in my whole servlet-context.xml if I could format it right, but I can't seem to in the comments.I do have <mvc:annotation-driven/> in there. is annotation-config different?

Comment: @ArunPJohny  I did what you said with downloading source but I cannot find it.  Where is it?  Where are the spring classes?

Comment: Go to some java file and paste `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.support.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`, then if you are using eclipse then `ctrl + click` on the class, it will ask you to attach the source file

Comment: If you can spend some time we can move to chat and try to find a solution

Comment: @ArunPJohny I can chat, I just can't start it because I don't have a high enough reputation

Comment: also I am using STS. and ctrl-click on the class in a class does nothing

Comment: @ArunPJohny no remote support tool, but I can skype.  I maybe found you on skype.  With no recognizable location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the explicit declaration of spring mvc mapping handlers along with `<mvc:annotation-conig />`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding following lines to your application context, It will fix the issue.

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```